# Change View in mvc based on dropdownlist item selection

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownlist on a View as:

```
<p>
@Html.DropDownList("Status", new List<SelectListItem>
    {
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Show Active", Value = "0" },
    new SelectListItem{ Text = "Show Deleted", Value = "1" }},
    new
         {
             onchange = @"
        var form = document.forms[0];
        form.action='deletedDistricts';
        form.submit();"
         })
```

and I am referring it to **controller** action as:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ActionName("deletedDistricts")]
    public ActionResult deletedDistricts()
    {
        var d = hc.deletedDistricts.ToList();
        return View(d);
    }
```

but JavaScript is giving a runtime error as:

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'action' of undefined or null reference

I am not very good at JavaScript. Any idea why this code is throwing Null reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I can't see that you would have a form associated with a dropdown, make sure that it's wrapped with:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("deletedDistricts", controllerName, FormMethod.Post)) {
    // drowpdown here
}
```

And remove

```
form.action='deletedDistricts';
```

*conrollerName* should be name of your controller as a string.

Answer (score 1):

Let's read the error you are getting once again:

> 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to set property 'action'
>   of undefined or null reference

OK, now let's read your code once again to see where you are attempting to set an `action` property. Looks like that's happening right over here:

```
form.action='deletedDistricts';
```

Alright, so it seems like the `form` instance is undefined at this stage. So the obvious next step you would like to look at is where is this `form` instance coming from. And you wouldn't be surprised to find this line of code of yours:

```
var form = document.forms[0];
```

Cool, you seem to be attempting to retrieve the first `<form>` element in your DOM. But do you have such element? Did you ever use the `Html.BeginForm` helper to render an HTML form? Answering those simple questions would definitely put you on the right track. Don't hesitate to inspect the markup you are generating in the browser. I am sure this would help you figure out the missing bits.

Comment: Thanks for the help and reply.